# Writing a simple application to inject messages onto a queue

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm trying to write a simple Java program to inject an MQ message onto a queue. I'm very inexperienced with writing to MQ queues using Java and have a couple of questions.

1. Can I connect to the unix queue on the unix box from my windows machine?
2. When I try to run the application I get a ....
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd05 in java.library.path

From the sounds of what I could find in google I am missing some sort of resource. I'm thinking I'm getting this error possibly bc I'm not allowed to connect to the queue from windows?

Any good examples of how to achieve what I'm doing or help would be appreciated.

```
public class MQInject {

    private MQQueueManager _queueManager = null;
    private Hashtable params = null;

    public int port = 1414;
    public static final String hostname    = "UQMYPOSIS1";
    public static final String channel     = "MQTX1012.MQTX1013";
    public static final String qManager    = "MQTX1013";
    public static final String outputQName = "IIS.TLOG.5";

    public MQInject(){
        super();
    }

    public void init(){

        //Set MQ connection credentials to MQ Envorinment.
         MQEnvironment.hostname = hostname;
         MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
         MQEnvironment.port = port;
         //MQEnvironment.userID = "";
         //QEnvironment.password = password;
         //set transport properties.
         MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);

         try {
             //initialize MQ manager.
             _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
        } catch (MQException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        MQInject write = new MQInject();
        try
        {
            write.selectQMgr();
            write.write();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Usage: java MQWrite <-h host> <-p port> <-c channel> <-m QueueManagerName> <-q QueueName>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch (MQException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private void selectQMgr() throws MQException
    {
      _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
    }    


    private void write() throws MQException{
     String line;
     int lineNum=0;
     int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

     try {
         MQQueue queue = _queueManager.accessQueue( outputQName,
                 openOptions,
                 null,           // default q manager
                 null,           // no dynamic q name
                 null );         // no alternate user id

         DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

         System.out.println("MQWrite v1.0 connected");
         System.out.println("and ready for input, terminate with ^Z\n\n");

         // Define a simple MQ message, and write some text in UTF format..
         MQMessage sendmsg               = new MQMessage();
         sendmsg.format                  = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
         sendmsg.feedback                = MQC.MQFB_NONE;
         sendmsg.messageType             = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
         sendmsg.replyToQueueName        = "ROGER.QUEUE";
         sendmsg.replyToQueueManagerName = qManager;

         MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();  // accept the defaults, same
                                 // as MQPMO_DEFAULT constant
         while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){
             sendmsg.clearMessage();
             sendmsg.messageId     = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
             sendmsg.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
             sendmsg.writeString(line);
             // put the message on the queue
             queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);
             System.out.println(++lineNum + ": " + line);
         }

         queue.close();
         _queueManager.disconnect();

        }catch (com.ibm.mq.MQException mqex){
            System.out.println(mqex);
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException ioex){
            System.out.println("An MQ IO error occurred : " + ioex);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, yes you can have a queue manager running on a UNIX host which is accessed by a client running on a Windows host.

For your second question, the mqjbnd05 library is only used to connect to the queue manager in binding mode (i.e. when the queue manager and the program accessing the queues are on the same host) and is not part of the MQ client installation. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21158430 for more details. Looking through your code I can see that the `init()` function is specifying `MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT` although I cannot see that the `init()` function is being called. Also it might be worth checking whether mqjbnd05 is specified in the library path and if so removing it.

Whilst probably not related to the error your getting, one other thing that might be worth checking is that the channel `MQTX1012.MQTX1013` is a server connection channel as opposed to a sender or receiver channel.